# dynamic gmapping in ROS

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is a general question.

Gmapping seems to be used only for creating a map of the static environment. Once created, it doesn't account for any changes - you add a new object, but it's being ignored and not reflected in the map.

Is there any way to modify gmapping so it can be used for changing environments? What other methods can be used in this case?

I don't care about localization, only need mapping of the dynamically changing environment.

Any thoughts or comments are very welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397817/dynamic-gmapping-in-ros/) by [nigeno](https://answers.ros.org/users/91893/nigeno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2022-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears like the term for dynamic mapping is life-long mapping.
There's an experimental implementation of this algorithm in [slam_toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox#lifelong-mapping)

Will test it out

---

Originally posted by [nigeno](https://answers.ros.org/users/91893/nigeno/) with karma: 76 on 2022-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0